# Proof that every real function has negative frequency component

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I want to know why every real function has negative frequency component. If I am not correct, can anyone tell me how it is really?

I heard that it is related to Fourier analysis, though not sure.

By the way, I am a high schooler graduating next year. I understand introductory calculus (calculus I, II, III in university level), so I do not think there will be any problem for me to understand explanation.

Comment: What does "negative frequency component" mean?

Comment: Google `Hermitian symmetry` of Fourier transform of real functions